# DataTemplate Selector after DataContext Set

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol, datatemplateselector

I have a DataGrid with 2 columns. Based on the first column which is bound to ParameterDataType I want to load the appropriate template in the second column.

Problem with this code is before the DataGrid has been loaded, the template selector is executing as a result the item is null. Is there a way to execute the Template Selector after the ControlTemplate's DataContext is set. Please help.

Here is my xaml:

```
<uwpControls:DataGrid Grid.Row="4"
                              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ServiceMethodsData,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                               AutoGenerateColumns="False">

<uwpControls:DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="StringTemplate">
                    <TextBox Width="150" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="IntegerTemplate">
                    <controls:TextBoxNumeric Width="150" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"></controls:TextBoxNumeric>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanTemplate">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="False"></CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
                <local:MethodValueDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MethodValueTemplateSelector"
                                               StringTemplate="{StaticResource StringTemplate}"
                                               IntegerTemplate="{StaticResource IntegerTemplate}"
                                               BooleanTemplate="{StaticResource BooleanTemplate}"/>
            </uwpControls:DataGrid.Resources>

 <uwpControls:DataGrid.Columns>

                <uwpControls:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Column"  
                                                Binding="{Binding ParameterDataType, Mode=OneWay}"/>

                <uwpControls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Second Column">
                    <uwpControls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="MethodValueContentControl"
                                            Content="{Binding Path=.}"
                                            ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MethodValueTemplateSelector}"></ContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </uwpControls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </uwpControls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </uwpControls:DataGrid.Columns>
        </uwpControls:DataGrid>
```

Here is my DataTemplate selector

```
public class MethodValueDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate StringTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate IntegerTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate BooleanTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            //I want to do something like if(DataContext.ParameterDataType=="Int") return IntegerTemplate etc
            return StringTemplate;
        }
    }
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
public class ServiceUtilityMethodsViewModel
{
        private ObservableCollection<VmServiceMethodsViewDataGridModel> _serviceMethodsData;
        public ObservableCollection<VmServiceMethodsViewDataGridModel> ServiceMethodsData
        {
            get => _serviceMethodsData;
            set => Set(ref _serviceMethodsData, value);
        }

        public ServiceUtilityMethodsViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            PopulateServiceData();
        }

        private void PopulateServiceData()
        {
            ServiceMethodsData = new ObservableCollection<VmServiceMethodsViewDataGridModel>();
            ServiceMethodsData.Add(new VmServiceMethodsViewDataGridModel()
            {
                ParameterName = "Param1",
                ParameterDataType = "String"
            });
            ServiceMethodsData.Add(new VmServiceMethodsViewDataGridModel()
            {
                ParameterName = "Param2",
                ParameterDataType = "Int"
            });
            ServiceMethodsData.Add(new VmServiceMethodsViewDataGridModel()
            {
                ParameterName = "Param3",
                ParameterDataType = "bool"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Model class

```
public class VmServiceMethodsViewDataGridModel : BindableBaseThreadSafe
    {
        private string _parameterName;
        private string _parameterDataType;

        public string ParameterName
        {
            get => _parameterName;
            set => Set(ref _parameterName, value);
        }
        public string ParameterDataType //I want the template selector to work based on this column.
        {
            get => _parameterDataType;
            set => Set(ref _parameterDataType, value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the `DataTemplateSelector` to `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector` and `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplateSelector` directly.

I didn't check the UWP version. I think the UWP `DataGridTemplateColumn` doesn't have this template selector properties. In this case you can stick to your current XAML, but don't forget to define a `CellEditingTemplate` too (e.g., replace the `TextBlock` with a `TextBox` for the `CellEditingTemplate` version - better use a `TextBlock` in your default `CellTemplate` as it looks better). The properties `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate` exist for sure in the UWP version.

**XAML `DataGrid` definition**

```
<uwpControls:DataGrid ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ServiceMethodsData,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <uwpControls:DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StringTemplate">
      <TextBox Width="150" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="IntegerTemplate">
      <controls:TextBoxNumeric Width="150" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanTemplate">
      <CheckBox IsChecked="False" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:MethodValueDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MethodValueTemplateSelector"
                                           StringTemplate="{StaticResource StringTemplate}"
                                           IntegerTemplate="{StaticResource IntegerTemplate}"
                                           BooleanTemplate="{StaticResource BooleanTemplate}" />
  </uwpControls:DataGrid.Resources>

  <uwpControls:DataGrid.Columns>
    <uwpControls:DataGridTextColumn Header="First Column"  
                                    Binding="{Binding ParameterDataType, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <uwpControls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Second Column"
                                        CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MethodValueTemplateSelector}"
                                        CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MethodValueTemplateSelector}">
    </uwpControls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </uwpControls:DataGrid.Columns>
</uwpControls:DataGrid>
```

The `DataTemplateSelector` is also quite simple.
The parameters of the `SelectTemplateCore` override are the item and the item's container (which is a `FrameWorkElement` and a `ContentControl` most of the time).
The item is always the data model and the `DataContext` of the current row. In your case the item is of type `VmServiceMethodsViewDataGridModel`.

The container is the `FrameWorkElement` that wraps the model for rendering e.g. `ListBoxItem`. In your case the container should be of type `DataGridRow`.

Simply cast the item parameter to the appropriate type and evaluate it.

**MethodValueDataTemplateSelector.cs**

```
public class MethodValueDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemplate StringTemplate { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate IntegerTemplate { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate BooleanTemplate { get; set; }

  protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    // Return if the control is not loaded yet and the item is therefore null    
    // or the item is of the wrong type
    if (!(item is VmServiceMethodsViewDataGridModel dataModel))
    {
      return null;
    }

    // I want to do something like: 
    // if(DataContext.ParameterDataType=="Int") return IntegerTemplate etc
    switch (dataModel.ParameterDataType)
    {
      case string value when value.Equals("Int", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase): 
        return IntegerTemplate;
      case string value when value.Equals("String", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase): 
        return StringTemplate;
      case string value when value.Equals("Bool", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase): 
        return BooleanTemplate;
      default: 
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works fine in  Wpf project but in UWP when i assign the cell editing template it throws an error. I will try using a simple listview rather than the toolkits DataGrid.

Comment: What is the error message? Maybe we can fix it. But if the `ListView` is sufficient for you, then why bother - except for the sake of understanding.

Comment: Yea a simple listview should do. But I just wanted to try with a DataGrid. When i try to assign the CellEditingTemplate it says, failed to assign property to uwpToolKit.CellEditing Template. The inner exception is null.

Comment: Also the same code I created a Wpf project and it works just fine.The only reason I am using a DataGrid is because it shows grid lines

Comment: I just tried it out with a ListView and it works fine also. Its only the uwpToolkit's cellediting template.

Comment: Maybe tomorrow I'll find time to check what's wrong with the UWP `DataGrid`. I will let you know in case I checked it and found some light. C you.

Comment: Sure thank you. I am pretty sure myself the uwpToolKit Datagrid CellEditingTemplate is buggy. Thats just my feeling.

Comment: Can you please help me with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965743/textbox-inside-a-listview-bound-to-an-object-two-way-binding-dosent-work

Comment: Hey @nikhil, nice to see you again. I checked your question and found it already answered. Do you still need help?

Comment: Hey @BionicCode thanks so much. I will try a different approach to my question writing a converter. Because the answer dosen't fit in completely to my use case it gives me an idea. I will try it and may be ask for help if I can't solve it. Thanks again

Comment: Hey @BionicCode Could you please help me with my new problem. I have updated my post here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61965743/textbox-inside-a-listview-bound-to-an-object-two-way-binding-dosent-work