# Property changed is not being triggered inside a Task

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

I have a simple app where I show a progress ring when some task is running and hide the progress ring as soon as it completes. Problem with this code is the Progress bar never gets collapsed.

I keep a break point in the value converter class and it never receives a value of false even after the value changes. As a result the ProgressRing never collapses. How can I fix this?

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class TestVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isRingVisible;
        public bool IsRingVisible
        {
            get => _isRingVisible;
            set
            {
                _isRingVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRingVisible));
            }
        }
        public TestVM()
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await DoSomething());
        }

        private async Task DoSomething()
        {
            IsRingVisible = true;
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            IsRingVisible = false; //Value set to false but when I have a break point in the value converter class, it never receives this value.
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

In the xaml I have a simple UI as follows,

```
<Page.Resources>
        <converter:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibility"/>
    </Page.Resources>
<Grid>
        <Border x:Name="BdrProgressRing" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                    Background="Red"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Opacity="0.6" 
                    Visibility="{x:Bind vm.IsRingVisible,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}">
        </Border>
        <ProgressRing x:Name="PgRing" 
                          Grid.Row="0" 
                          Grid.RowSpan="2"
                          Visibility="{Binding ElementName=BdrProgressRing, Path=Visibility}"
                          IsActive="True"  
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Width="90"
                          Height="90"/>
    </Grid>
```

Here is my xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public TestVM vm { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            vm = new TestVM();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Since I called it inside a Task I need to use a Dispatcher I guess.

Comment: Sure I will read about it thanks.

Comment: Don't use `Dispatcher` if possible. It can give the code a monster-look. If you want to send back to UI Thread something from concurrent `Task` in the middle of execution, you may use a synchronized callback class `Progress` which implements `IProgress` interface. It's simple as while-true. It executes its delegate in that Context where it was constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```cs
Task.Run(async () => await DoSomething()) ;
```

To

```cs
_ = DoSomething();
```

Probably you allowed to change the property only from Main UI Thread, not from pooled `Task`. Learn more about Synchronization Context in WPF.

---

However, the above is bad practice. Any async method should be awaited. Simply assigning the Task returned from `DoSomething()` to a local variable is not sufficient.

Since you can't await in a constructor, the view model should have a public awaitable method that is actually awaited by the caller, e.g.

```
public TestVM()
{
}

public Task Initialize()
{
    return DoSomething();
}
```

Then call `await vm.Initialize();` in an async Loaded event handler in the view:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new TestVM();
    DataContext = this;

    Loaded += async (s, e) => await vm.Initialize();
}
```

Comment: Hi @aepot can you help me with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62687039/property-changed-is-not-updating-the-ui-from-inside-a-task I thought its same as this one but it didn't solve my problem there.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the useful edits. I prefer to keep it. But i can't see the technical difference between direct call like Fire-and-Forget and `async void` lambda which used for `Load` in the updated answer. The logical difference is where you must handle the possible exceptions: in `DoSomethingAsync` or in lambda. Thus i can't say that's unsafe Fire-and-Forget is bad practice. In both ways the developer must take care of possible `Exception` catching. Also i like [this](https://johnthiriet.com/removing-async-void/) approach.

Comment: It's not about any exceptions. The point is to *always* await an awaitable method - except event handlers, where this isn't possible.

Comment: @Clemens In the same manner you may create some `async void`, it's not awaitable. Btw, `async void` Event handler is just an `async void` method, technically no difference. Maybe `async void` is better than discarding `async Task` (which you may `await` in another `async` method in the code because this method may be called not only in `.ctor`), I don't know. Ok, let it be. Thanks!

Comment: You *never* declare an `async void` method, except when it is an event handler.

Comment: @Clemens agree, but it looks like a kind of superstition. Why I can't use some implementation when it's exaclty what I need? Wrapping fire-and-forget call into Event Handler it's redunant and tangled thing especially for this exact case. If discarding `Task` is bad practice, it's ok. I agree but then I prefer `async void` wrapper with `try-catch` inside. And yes, I'll keep this secret way to fire-and-forget and will not tell anyone. _Let me know when you'll done reading this, I'll delete this message. :)_

Comment: "*I can't use some implementation when it's exaclty what I need?* . that's not the point. Keep in mind you are writing an answer on StackOverflow, which is read by many people that aren't experts.

Comment: @Clemens _that's not the point_ Got it. I just know how it works and it doesn't allow me sleep. Thank you for the proper explanations, I have no more objections on it.